# Google Chrome does not have permissions to "see" dialog boxes

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, permission

I am a huge fan of automating my workflow with Keyboard Maestro, a kind of uber macro tool that can run script steps, execute Applescript or Javascript, save variables and do lots of other stuff.

I have a script step that waits for buttons (OK/Cancel) to be present, i.e. because a dialog has opened, the script can proceed. On one of my Macs this works perfectly, but on the other two, Google Chrome seems to have asked for permission to access dialog boxes but been denied (because I didn't notice it in time). Thus, Chrome refuses to "see" the buttons in the dialog that has opened.

I've played with permissions in Privacy and Security: automation, screen recording, files and Folders, full disk access, input monitoring, etc. I've toggled them off and on again. But nothing I change fixes the permission Google Chrome needs to access on-screen dialog boxes.

Can anyone suggest something to try?

I am running 100% Apple Silicon and fully updated Sonoma.